# Using datetime delete Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm using

```
df = df.groupby(['Sequence_ID','Altitude_[m]']).mean()
```

but the groupby removes my Timestamp column. Why?
My original df:

```
                        Timestamp  Sequence_ID  ...  CNR_[dB]  Confidence_Index_Status
0     2019-04-04 23:01:00.147     119569.0  ...    -11.66                      1.0
```

After groupby:

```
                              Azimuth_[°]  Elevation_[°]  ...  CNR_[dB]  Confidence_Index_Status
Sequence_ID Altitude_[m]                              ...                                   
119569.0    100.0                 0.0         89.999  ...   -11.660                      1.0
            150.0                 0.0         89.999  ...   -12.890                      1.0
```

And Timestamp is gone.

Comment: but what would the mean of a timestamp really be though? It doesn't make sense, for the same reason that string columns would be removed

Comment: I only want, that the timestamp is also in the list. At the moment it is deleted. so I mean, I also want a mean of the time.

Comment: How could the timestamp be in your list if you group rows? Which timestamp would you expect to be kept?

Comment: If i make a mean over all row... for me it also should make a mean of the timestamp. Or I'm wrong?!?

Comment: it seems `mean` only works with numerical data. You may want `groupby().agg({'Timestamp': 'first', 'Azimuth_[°]':'mean'})`.

Comment: Do I get the same as my groupby-code? It seems, that I have another groupby order: Time, Altitude, and this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groupyby is not the only operation you perform. 
You first perform a groupby and secondly perform a mean computation.

Looking into the documentation of [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), it seems that not all columns are used.

To test this you could seperate both operations and perform them subsequently.

> numeric_only : bool, default None Include only float, int, boolean
>   columns. If None, will attempt to use everything, then use only
>   numeric data. Not implemented for Series.